# Cygnus to CKAN: Possibly the organization already exists in a deleted state

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, ckan, fiware-cygnus

I have Cygnus configured to store all entities coming from Orion to CKAN. 
When I try to store the information from the entities in `http://demo.ckan.org/` everything works fine, organization, dataset and resource are created correctly, but when I try to store it in my own instance of CKAN I get this error.

```
time=2016-02-17T13:45:59.560CET | lvl=ERROR | trans=1455713068-242-0000000000 | srv=test | subsrv=test | function=processNewBatches | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink[424] : Runtime error (Don't know how to treat the response code. Possibly the organization already exists in a deleted state (respCode=403, orgName=test))
```

I have Cygnus 0.12.1-16, Orion 0.27.0-1 and CKAN 2.5.1 installed in my environment.

I am using `attr_persistence=row` to store data

Comment: I will need the full trace of Cygnus when running in DEBUG mode. Use a pastebin service or similar to post it. Thanks!

Comment: @frb [http://pastebin.com/vZ412g7S](http://pastebin.com/vZ412g7S)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logs, I've seen the following:

> time=2016-02-17T15:12:38.517CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1455718235-272-0000000000 | srv=test | subsrv=test | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[86] :  << "{"help": "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/help_show?name=organization_create", "success": false, "error": {"message": "Access denied: User 3e5bb58b-345b-4587-9905-e06c72091dc9 not authorized to create organizations", "__type": "Authorization Error"}}"

It seems there is some kind of problem with your user account in `demo.ckan.org`, you are not allowed to create organizations. Did you put the appropriate API token?

Comment: The problem is not in demo.ckan.org, I have the problem in my own installation of CKAN , but it has been solved , the problem was that the user did not have permission to edit and create organizations, datastore ...

Thank you very much

Comment: OK. Anyway... the above log was referring to `demo.ckan.org` :)